SpresenseとIIS3DWBでの通信ができません
Spresense + 拡張ボードの環境でIIS3DWBの加速度センサを利用したいと考えています．
Arduino IDEでプログラムを作成しています．
事前にArduinoでは動作確認済みのコードを使って，Spresenseで動作させようとしたところ「IIS3DWB not functioning!」と出て，getChipID関数で正しくデバイスのIDが取得できません．
ソースコードを添付しますので，何かお気づきの点があればご助言いただきたいです．
なお，拡張ボードの電圧設定は5V，IIS3DWBとSpresenseの結線は以下の通りです．



Spresense
IIS3DWB




3.3V
3.3V


SPI CS(D10)
SS


SPI MOSI(D11)
MOSI


SPI MISO(D12)
MISO


SPI SCK(D13)
SCK


GND
GND



#include <IIS3DWB.h>
#include "SPI.h"

#define SerialDebug true  // set to true to get Serial output for debugging
#define CSPIN    10

/* Specify sensor parameters (sample rate is same as the bandwidth 6.3 kHz by default)
 * choices are:  AFS_2G, AFS_4G, AFS_8G, AFS_16G  
*/ 
uint8_t Ascale = AFS_4G;

float aRes;                              // scale resolutions per LSB for the accel 
float accelBias[3] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}; // offset biases for the accel 
int16_t IIS3DWBData[4] = {0};                  // Stores the 16-bit signed sensor output
float ax, ay, az, accelTemp;             // variables to hold latest accel data values 
uint8_t IIS3DWBstatus;

volatile bool IIS3DWB_DataReady = true, IIS3DWB_Wakeup = true;

IIS3DWB IIS3DWB(CSPIN); // instantiate IIS3DWB class

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(4000);

  SPI.begin(); // Start SPI serial peripheral
  Serial.print("SPI Start!\n");

  // Configure SPI ship select for sensor breakout
  pinMode(CSPIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(CSPIN, HIGH); // disable SPI at start

  // Read the IIS3DWB Chip ID register, this is a good test of communication
  Serial.println("IIS3DWB accel...");
  uint8_t c = IIS3DWB.getChipID();  // Read CHIP_ID register for IIS3DWB
  Serial.print("IIS3DWB "); Serial.print("I AM "); Serial.print(c, HEX); Serial.print(" I should be "); Serial.println(0x7B, HEX);
  Serial.println(" ");

  if(c == 0x7B) // check if all SPI sensors have acknowledged
  {
   Serial.println("IIS3DWB is online...");  
   Serial.println(" ");

   // reset IIS3DWB to start fresh
   IIS3DWB.reset();

   // get accel sensor resolution, only need to do this once
   aRes = IIS3DWB.getAres(Ascale);

   IIS3DWB.selfTest();

   IIS3DWB.init(Ascale); // configure IIS3DWB  

   IIS3DWB.offsetBias(accelBias);
   Serial.println("accel biases (mg)"); Serial.println(1000.0f * accelBias[0]); Serial.println(1000.0f * accelBias[1]); Serial.println(1000.0f * accelBias[2]);
   Serial.println(" ");
   delay(1000); 

  }
  else 
  {
  if(c != 0x6A) Serial.println(" IIS3DWB not functioning!"); 
  while(1){};
  }

 }
/* End of setup */

void loop() {
  
  if(IIS3DWB_DataReady)  // Handle data ready condition
  {
    IIS3DWBstatus = IIS3DWB.DRstatus(); // read data ready status
    if (IIS3DWBstatus & 0x01) {         // if new accel data is available, read it
      IIS3DWB.readAccelData(IIS3DWBData);  
      // Now we'll calculate the accleration value into actual g's
        ax = (float)IIS3DWBData[0]*aRes - accelBias[0];  // get actual g value, this depends on scale being set
        ay = (float)IIS3DWBData[1]*aRes - accelBias[1];   
        az = (float)IIS3DWBData[2]*aRes - accelBias[2];  
       }
     }  // end of data ready interrupt handlin

   // end sensor interrupt handling
    
  if(SerialDebug) { // report latest accel data
    Serial.print("ax = "); Serial.print((int)1000*ax);  
    Serial.print(" ay = "); Serial.print((int)1000*ay); 
    Serial.print(" az = "); Serial.print((int)1000*az); Serial.println(" mg");
    }

  IIS3DWBData[3] = IIS3DWB.readTempData(); // get IIS3DWB chip temperature
  accelTemp = ((float) IIS3DWBData[3]) / 256.0f + 25.0f; // Accel chip temperature in degrees Centigrade
  // Print temperature in degrees Centigrade      
  if(SerialDebug) {
    Serial.print("IIS3DWB temperature is ");  Serial.print(accelTemp, 1);  Serial.println(" degrees C"); // Print T values to tenths of a degree C
    }

}
/*  End of main loop */

追記：
シリアルモニタに表示されたメッセージは以下の通りです．
IIS3DWB accel...
IIS3DWB I AM 0 I should be 7B
 
IIS3DWB not functioning!


電源入れてからの通信ログをすべて提示しましょう。ここに出すのではなく、質問文に追記するようにしてください

https://developer.sony.com/spresense/development-guides/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_機能と制限
SpresenseボードはSPIトランザクションに応じてCSピンが自動で制御されるようです。
言い換えると、CSピンをソフトウェアによって制御することができないので、
上記マニュアルにも書かれている通り、SPI CSにD10ピンを使うのをやめて、
他の空いているピンを割り当てれば動作するのではないかと思います。
例えば、D02ピンが空いていれば、IIS3DWBのSSピンをD02と結線して、
スケッチのCSPINを変更してみてください。
#define CSPIN    2 // 10 -> 2 へ変更


ご丁寧な回答ありがとうございます．
CSのピンをD02ピンに変更して試してみたところ，
'IIS3DWB accel...
IIS3DWB I AM 74 I should be 7B
IIS3DWB not functioning!
'
と表示され，今まで同様，正しくデバイスのIDを取得できませんでした．
他のデジタルピンで試してみたのですが，同様の状況となりました．

いままでは"0"が読めてたけど、"74"が読めるようになったということでしょうか。IIS3DWB.getChipID();を繰り返し実行しても常に同じ値(74)が返ってくるのでしょうか？それと、SPISettings()でSPI_MODE0を指定しているとしたらこれをSPI_MODE3に変更してみるとどうなるでしょうか？

D10ピンを使用した時のみ"0"と表示され，ほかのデジタルピンに変更した場合"74"と表示されています．繰り返し実行しても値は変わりませんでした．SPI_MODE0とSPI_MODE3を使用できるすべてのデジタルピンで試しましたが，シリアルモニタに表示される内容は変わりませんでした．

センサが壊れていたようで新しいものに変更したところ計測ができるようになりました．ただ，D10ピンでは今までと同様正しくデバイスのIDが取得できず，D02ピンで計測できました．ご助言ありがとうございました．
